# Find the area of the triangle $BDE$ if $\angle ABC = 60°$, $BD = BH$, and $BE = BO = 1$.

Tags: geometry

In the triangle $ABC$, $\angle ABC = 60°$. $O$ is its circumcentre and $H$ is its orthocentre. $D$ is a point on $BC$ such that $BD = BH$. $E$ is a point on $AB$ such that $BE = BO$. If $BO = 1$, what is the area of the triangle $BDE$?

[image: Picture]

The problem is taken from [here](http://imc-official.chiuchang.org/files/problem/2008-IWYMIC-Individual.pdf). I know the answer is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$, but how can I prove it? That would mean that $BD = 1$, so the triangle $BED$ would be equilateral.

Can you give me a hint, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R'$ be the radius of the circumcircle of $\triangle{BCH}$.

By the law of sines,
$$1=\frac{BC}{2\sin{\angle{BAC}}},\quad R'=\frac{BC}{2\sin{\angle{BHC}}}\tag1$$

Since $\angle{BHC}=180^\circ-\angle{BAC}$, we have
$$\sin{\angle{BHC}}=\sin{\angle{BAC}}\tag2$$

From $(1),(2)$, we have
$$R'=1$$

So, $$BD=BH=2R'\sin{\angle{HCB}}=2\sin(90^\circ-\angle{ABC})=1$$
from which
$$[BED]=\frac 12\times BD\times BE\times\sin{60^\circ}=\frac 12\times 1\times 1\times\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}=\frac{\sqrt 3}{4}$$
follows.

Comment: How do you know $sin\angle HCB=sin(90^\circ-\angle ABC)$?

Comment: @Tyrone: Let $F$ be the intersection point of $AB$ with $CH$. Since $\triangle{CFB}$ is a right triangle, we get $\angle{ABC}+\angle{HCB}=90^\circ$.